# google identity services equivalent for googleUser.getBasicProfile()

Tags: authentication, google-api, google-identity

I have a react app where I'm trying to migrate from using gapi.auth2 module in the Google API Client Library for JavaScript to the Google Identity Services Library.

With gapi.auth2 module you could get the signed in users basic profile info with  `googleUser.getBasicProfile()`. The following code is how you log a user in with the Google Identity Services Library.

**Login.js**

```
function Login(){
    var tokenClient;
    var access_token;

    function getToken(){
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
    }

    function initGis(){

        tokenClient = window.google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: '********.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/books',
            callback: (tokenResponse) => {
                access_token = tokenResponse.access_token;
            },//end of callback:
            
        });
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        initGis();
        getToken();  
    });

    return (
        <>
        <p>Logging in...</p>
        </>             
    )
}

export default Login;
```

How do you get the users basic profile info when using the Google Identity Services Library?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Cooper Sorry. What is not specific about the question I asked? How do you get the users basic info when using the Google Identity Services Library  to log a user in?

Comment: The difficulty for many of us is that we may often only cover a subset of the selected tags.    In my case, I'm only interested in dealing with google apps script questions so from my standpoint your question was to broad. But I'm taking your objection into consideration in the future and I'll try to do better.

Answer (score 3):

Let me keep this answer short.  Once you get the `access_token` just invoke the following function:

```js
const getUserProfileData = async (accessToken: string) => {
  const headers = new Headers()
  headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`)
  const response = await fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo', {
    headers
  })
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

PS: [Unfortunately] I am also working on migrating to Google Identity Services Library.

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion on Discord where a very helpful user explained that it can only be done server side. So the simple answer is that it can't be done client side using the Google Identity Services Library

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same issue migrating my web app to Google Identity Services. I resolved it by using the Google Drive API `About:get` method, and requested `user` fields. This returns the user's `displayName` and `emailAddress` (plus some other data that's really not very useful). I use the `drive.readonly` scope, but I believe a less sensitive scope like `drive.appdata` or `drive.file` would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function getTokenInfos(token) {
    var splitResponse = token.split(".");
    var infos = JSON.parse(atob(splitResponse[1]));
    return infos;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).