# How to get user details after Google Authentication

Tags: javascript, html, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="MYCLIENTID"
         data-context="signin"
         data-ux_mode="popup"
         data-callback="callbackFunction"
         data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>

    <div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-shape="pill"
         data-theme="filled_black"
         data-text="signin_with"
         data-size="large"
         data-logo_alignment="left">
    </div>
    <script>
        function callbackFunction() {
            console.log("signed in");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is what I want to do, I got this code from [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/people?hl=en), but this is old and not working anymore.

```
var profile = auth2.currentUser.get().getBasicProfile();
  console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
  console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
  console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
  console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
  console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
  console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
```

I tried asking ChatGPT and checked library's documentation from Google but couldn't find anything. ChatGPT tells me the old methods and its not working.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: When I try the code console shows the error "getBasicProfile is not a function" because this code is the old method. I need that code's new version

Comment: If that's the case, please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71973552/google-identity-services-equivalent-for-googleuser-getbasicprofile) and the answers within.